# Formatting text with vim

Tags: vim, formatting

I have a file with 275 lines of code. The lines are constant declarations in c.
e.g

```
      71 #define LM_HOST_ALLOWED             3100 //Boolean.
```

My problem is that it has many duplicate lines since I created that file by copying and pasting from other files and the lines are not the same 100%

e.g

```
      71 #define LM_HOST_ALLOWED             3100 //Boolean.
      72 #define LM_HOST_ALLOWED               3100 //Boolean.
```

Is there a way in vim to find those lines and keep only one of those. Or is there a way to format all lines to have the number (3100 in our case) factor at a certain level? e.g 6 tabs or something? I started doing it manually but it's a pain entering and leaving edit mode. PLS HELP! If this question doesn't make sense please help me improve it.

**edit:**
I found a solution about formating the text:
in vim's normal mode I type:

`qa0f f 50i <esc>38|dwjq274@a`
 and it does the job. I'm really glad I found this (in this forum as well)
the problem now is that the `uniq` command doesn't do what I'm reading it should do. In vim I type :!uniq but not all duplicate lines get deleted. I'm thinking that it could be because of tab instead of spaces in some places. Any information about that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tabular.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3464) to line up the numbers, use something like this:

```
:Tabularize / [0-9]\{4\}/l2c1
```

This will line up all numbers with 4 digits (`3100` in this case) in this way:

```
71 #define LM_HOST_ALLOWED  3100 //Boolean.
72 #define LM_HOST_ALLOWED  3100 //Boolean.
```

Comment: There's also the Align plugin so you can do stuff like line up code on equals signs or commas or whatever. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294

Answer (score 0):

If maintaining the order is not important, you can use

```
:%sort u
```

to sort the contents and keep only one instance of each line. (Assuming you have first canonicalized the line format with *Align* or *Tabularize*.)

---

If you need to maintain the order, my [SearchPosition plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634) may be handy. With its <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> mapping, it shows the number of occurrences of the current word in the buffer. You could go through each line to check for duplicates.

---

In case you do this often (and can't fix the root cause of the problem, i.e. the entry of duplicates), you can write a custom command that parses all lines with `getline()` and `split()`, and then jumps to the first duplicate line it finds; it's probably just a few lines of Vimscript.